# : and := inside a bash parameter expansion

Tags: bash, dockerfile

Trying to understand a dockerfile written in bash.
What is : for?

```
: ${WORDPRESS_DB_USER:=root}
```

And :=?

I put more code from the script for reference:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

if [ -n "$MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP" ]; then
    if [ -z "$WORDPRESS_DB_HOST" ]; then
        WORDPRESS_DB_HOST='mysql'
    else
        echo >&2 'warning: both WORDPRESS_DB_HOST and MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP found'
        echo >&2 "  Connecting to WORDPRESS_DB_HOST ($WORDPRESS_DB_HOST)"
        echo >&2 '  instead of the linked mysql container'
    fi
fi

if [ -z "$WORDPRESS_DB_HOST" ]; then
    echo >&2 'error: missing WORDPRESS_DB_HOST and MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP environment variables'
    echo >&2 '  Did you forget to --link some_mysql_container:mysql or set an external db'
    echo >&2 '  with -e WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=hostname:port?'
    exit 1
fi

# if we're linked to MySQL, and we're using the root user, and our linked
# container has a default "root" password set up and passed through... :)
: ${WORDPRESS_DB_USER:=root}
if [ "$WORDPRESS_DB_USER" = 'root' ]; then
    : ${WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD:=$MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
fi
: ${WORDPRESS_DB_NAME:=wordpress}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`:` is simply a command that does nothing. However, the arguments for the command are still evaluated.

`${WORDPRESS_DB_NAME:=wordpress}` is a parameter expansion that check if `WORDPRESS_DB_NAME` is unset or has the empty string for a value. If either is true, the parameter is assigned the value `wordpress`. The result of the expansion is then the (possibly newly assigned) value of `WORDPRESS_DB_NAME`.

Together, they form a common shell idiom for setting the value of a variable if it does not already have a (non-null) value.

A (non-DRY) Python equivalent might be

```
try:
    if not WORDPRESS_DB_NAME:
        WORDPRESS_DB_NAME = "wordpress"
except NameError:
    WORDPRESS_DB_NAME = "wordpress"
```